# Ajaxify submitting the woocommerce review form

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Since the default behavior breaks the shopping experience in my opinion, I would like to use Ajax to submit the woocommerce review form.

I've used jQuery.ajax() to post the form but If someone is not logged in, all I get back are errors. Even when all the form fields (rating, comment, author and email address) are filled out.

Please help me out!

**Edit -- added the code I tried**

```
jQuery('document').ready(function($){

    $( '#review_form' ).append( '<div id="comment-status"></div>' );

    var commentform = $('#commentform'); 
    var statusDiv   = $('#comment-status')

    commentform.submit(function(){  

        var formdata    = commentform.serialize(); 
        var formurl     = commentform.attr('action'); 

        statusDiv.html( '<p class="wdpajax-error">Bezig met verwerken...</p>' ); 

        $.ajax({  

            type: 'post',  
            url: formurl,  
            data: formdata,  

            error: function( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

                console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);

                statusDiv.html( '<p class="alert alert-danger" >Je hebt een van de verplichte velden leeg gelaten of te snel nog een reactie geplaatst</p>' ); 

            },  

            success: function( data, textStatus ) {  

                if( textStatus == "success" )  { 

                    commentform.hide();                 
                    statusDiv.html(' <p class="alert alert-success" ><strong>Bedankt voor je beoordeling!</strong> Het kan even duren voordat hij op de site verschijnt, aangezien we hem nog moeten controleren</p>' );  

                } else { 

                    statusDiv.html( '<p class="alert alert-warning">Je hebt een van de verplichte velden leeg gelaten of te snel nog een reactie geplaatst</p>' );  
                    commentform.find( 'textarea[name=comment]' ).val( '' );  

                }

            } 

        });

        return false;    

    });     

});
```

Comment: Can you share the `code` you've done so far?

Comment: I added the code I tried

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code and should work fine, just make sure you enter the name(author)/email (if you're still having an error even if you filled all the fields please specify the error)

Comment: Right now I tested it and if I submit an complete empty form I get the success alert back... So there must be something going wrong!

Comment: I see the problem in case of error, you are not checking the server's response to the ajax request. checking the statusText won't work, so you can change that into something like `if( textStatus == "success" && !data.match(/error-page/g))` in your success function, it will check if wordpress hasn't responded with an error page (not the best solution but it will work)